# How to put data to req body

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, req

Welcome again. I have a problem with POST route. My question is: is it possible to get data as an array from li tag in req.body?

HTML code:

```
<form class="form" action="/creator" method="POST">
  <div class="selected-users">
    <h3>Added Users:</h3>
    <ul class="selected-users-list" name="players">
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>

<div class="container2">
  <div class="tournament-users">
    <h3>Users to add</h3>
    <div class="alert-user-selected"></div>
    <div class="select-box">
      <div class="options-container">
        <% for ( let user of users ) { %>
          <div class="option">
            <input type="radio" class="radio" name="user">
            <label class="user-login" for="<%= user.login %>" id="<%= user._id %>"><%= user.login %></label>
          </div>
        <% } %>
      </div>
      <div class="selected">
        <input class="find-user" type="text" placeholder="Select User">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In JS code I am putting in tag `ul` my selected users as `li` tag.
In my POST route when I `console.log(req.body)` I cant't see my picked players/users despite the fact that my players are added on my page when I pick them, but they don't exists in req.body.

My final question is: How to past them to req.body as array or Object.

Thanks and Best regards.

Karollo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the user into the HTML as follows If you want to get them from the request body:

```
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="user[]">
```